# Divide one GitHub commit into more than one

Tags: git, github, commit, pull-request

I made a Pull Request that had only one commit. This commit includes some changes like: 
adding `function a()` and `function b()`.

How can I divide this commit into two commits, so 
**the first commit** will have the changes related to `function a()`
**the second commit** will have the changes related to `function b()`

Can I do this? and How?

 Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+split+commit

Comment: After rewriting history with `rebase` or `reset` you need to force push the branch: `git push --force`